# Emulators doesn't run at Xubuntu 12.04

Tags: android, android-emulator, xubuntu

I'm newly at android. I installed android SDK and configured few emulators to work with applications.

But problem is that no one doesn't work when I lunch it.

I'm using Xubuntu 12.04.

Here is how looks virtual device manager:

[image: device manager]

And one configuration:

[image: ARM]

Here is more info about PC characteristic:

```
nazar@nazar-desctop:~$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 15
model       : 107
model name  : AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 4000+
stepping    : 1
cpu MHz     : 2109.755
cache size  : 512 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 1
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt rdtscp lm 3dnowext 3dnow rep_good nopl extd_apicid pni cx16 lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy 3dnowprefetch lbrv
bogomips    : 4219.51
TLB size    : 1024 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: ts fid vid ttp tm stc 100mhzsteps

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 15
model       : 107
model name  : AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 4000+
stepping    : 1
cpu MHz     : 2109.755
cache size  : 512 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 1
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt rdtscp lm 3dnowext 3dnow rep_good nopl extd_apicid pni cx16 lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy 3dnowprefetch lbrv
bogomips    : 4219.14
TLB size    : 1024 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: ts fid vid ttp tm stc 100mhzsteps
```

It should works. I tried this configuration at my old OS - Ubuntu 12.04 (exactly worked only one with ARM processor and android 2.3).

But here even emulator window doesn't appear.

One more things I can't delete any emulators. I t prints that `emulator is running and can't be deleted`:

[image: can't delete]

But I only started sdk. This looks very strange.

***Why exactly this happen? How to solve this trouble?***

Comment: Might sound dumb, but "have you tried to turn it off and on again"?

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo yep I did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `$HOME` folder, find `.android` hidden folder. Then there should be `avd` folder. There should be your `AVDNAME.INI` and a folder with same AVD name. Delete them both, re-create them from beginning. Don't use high memory values, create a basic simple AVD, then run it. Also as Stefano in comments suggested, consider rebooting OS.

Answer (score 1):

When the emulator starts, it tries to restore the virtual device's window to its previous position. Normally, it can even detect that the window is out-of-view, and recenter it.

Unfortunately, this is unreliable with certain Linux window managers, and it may be possible that the emulator did start, but is hidden for some reason. That would explain why you cannot delete an emulator. Try to see if your window manager allows you to list all active windows and move/center them. Try another window manager if you can too.

Otherwise, what exactly happens when you start an emulator? Do you see a window? An error message? Anything?

Apart from that, 312 MB of RAM is probably too low for an xdpi device, try raising this to 512 instead.